# Unwanted height constraint animates when setting UIProgressView progress

Tags: ios, swift, animation, storyboard, uiprogressview

So I have a UIProgressview in storyboard and I set the height constraint via storyboard and it's the height I expect and everything with that is sunshine and rainbows.

My problem comes into play when I'm setting the progress of it, I call 
`cell.progressBar.setProgress(22, animated: true)` 
(I'm using tableview cells btw for multiple progress bars)
and it fills the bar as expected BUT it also animates the height constraint so it goes from a height of 9 to a height of 25 or whatever I set. 
 I don't want this behavior.

Also it's worth mentioning that when I have other cells with progress bars in them and I only need to set 1, the other progress bars don't animate their height constraint, they simply have an empty bar with correct height (what I expect).

And I want to note that I'm setting the progress for every cell (variable number of cells) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`so I'm not sure why setting the progress animates the height constraint and not setting the progress has the height constraint already fixed like I want. I do want the fill animation just without the height constraint being animated also.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for cell for row if it helps

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basic_result_cell", for: indexPath) as! BasicResultCell

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

        cell.progressBar.setProgress((Int(25))%, animated: true)
    })

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Pls show us your actual code. Are you adding your ui manipulation in the main thread?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh I don't think it's a thread issue but here's my code for cellforRow

Comment: @BadhanGanesh Turns out it was a thread issue :D thanks for the help

Comment: That’s cool! (y)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Badhan for pointing it might be a thread issue.
 here's what I did to fix it. Probably due to it being a closure or something. Anywho this works.

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           cell.progressBar.setProgress((Int(25))%, animated: true)
       }
   })
```